# MD5 Checksum with optional 128/256/512/1024/2048-bit size in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, md5, rsa, checksum

Is it possible to use **MD5** to get checksum that would have optional size of 128/256/512/1024/2048-bit?

The `Digest::MD5` module allows to use the RSA MD5 Message Digest algorithm that takes as input a message of arbitrary length and produces as output a **128-bit fingerprint**.

How can be used MD5 to produce **larger** fingerprint?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - How fast is SHA-2 (SHA-512)..?

Comment: @Ωmega that's a tricky question. Normally I would say it is about 4 times slower than MD5, but it depends a lot on implementation and CPU (SHA-512 is an algorithm based on 64 bit values, so it is pretty fast on newer CPU's and can be made faster using vector graphics or GPU's)

Comment: Could you indicate what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @owlstead - Thanks! I am looking for checksum algorithm that would produce larger footprint, however the encryption quality and speed are most important issues.

Comment: Regarding the quality, there is little to nothing to be gained if you go over 512 bits, so you might as well stick to that. If anything breaks, it's the algorithm, which is kind of unrelated to the output size. A good 512 bit hash is equivalent to AES-256 bits encryption (see [keylength.com](http://www.keylength.com/) for more information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a MD5 hash of that size. In general, secure hash functions have been designed for a specific size. They have an internal state of a certain size.

Of course, you can use MD5 to create a random stream of bytes; just take the previous value and hash again, and keep appending the results. Of course, the total security of the results will be no stronger than the original hash value over the data. After a while the hashes will become weaker, as a little amount of entropy is lost after each hash (this will take pretty long though).

Currently the best hash function you can use is SHA-512, although it will be slowly replaced by SHA-3 of the identical size (but that has not been standardized at the time of writing). These hash values provide more than enough security, so if you need more data you could simply use a padding method.

The padding methods that come to mind are:

- proprietary method to simply add an X number of bytes with known value;
- the function as used within PBKDF2;
- the function as used internally for PSS padding (see the public RSA PKCS#1 v2.1 standards).

As said, it depends on the application which one is the best to use. If you don't know what you are doing (such as it seems), *don't use MD5*. It's too broken for general use, and it does not have a big enough state or output.

Answer (score 3):

MD5 [by definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321) produces only a 128-bit hash value.

Therefore, you'll either need to use a different hash function (for instance, the [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family of hash functions outputs values up to [512 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions)) or break your data into parts and hash those, combining the hashes afterward.

If you could give more detail about what you're trying to achieve then it would make giving more specific recommendations easier.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. See the [cPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Digest-MD5/MD5.pm):

```
 # Functional style
 use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);

 $digest = md5($data);
 $digest = md5_hex($data);
 $digest = md5_base64($data);
```

The Digest::MD5 module allows you to use the RSA Data Security Inc. MD5 Message Digest algorithm from within Perl programs. The algorithm takes as input a message of arbitrary length and produces as **output a 128-bit "fingerprint"** or "message digest" of the input.

Note that the MD5 algorithm is not as strong as it used to be. It has since 2005 been easy to generate different messages that produce the same MD5 digest. It still seems hard to generate messages that produce a given digest, but it is probably wise to move to stronger algorithms for applications that depend on the digest to uniquely identify a message.

- You may look into using [RSA](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=rsa&mode=all) instead.

Comment: RSA cannot directly be used as a hash method, so that's not really an option, Lo Sauer. Pointing to the perl documentation is not conclusive regarding the algorithm (implementations may not implement all functionality, and documentation is often pretty thin).

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that. It is meant as a sidenote. Initially I wanted to link directly to the `pssh-keygen` module, but the CPAN search on RSA was better suited nonetheless...